# what daemon/service can I use to block website based on page content?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy

might be best explained with an example:

On the page I'm viewing, the word "sex" is present in the  DOM or page source or URL. I want to block this page and present a generic page instead.

also it would be greeat if it can block pages based on multiple words (example: breaking bad)

---

I've looked at various squid tutorials (which included tutorials on squid extensions) and it seems this is not possible.

Thanks

Edit: I don't mind if it blocks pages where sex is a substring on another word (example: Wessex or sextant and etc)

Comment: Is it OK to you that this will also block sites containing the words sextant, Wessex... aswell as anything having `sex` as a variable name internally, i.e. for gender? If not, consider being more precise in what you want to filter.

Comment: No problem with that! This is for my young son. He wouldn't be searching for those! Suggest away